# How does webpack's require work?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I don't understand how webpack's `require` function work. For example, I'm reading [this article](http://blog.madewithlove.be/post/webpack-your-bags/) about webpack and there is the following example:

> Let's start by creating our project and installing Webpack, we'll also
>   pull in jQuery to demonstrate some things later on.

```
$ npm init
$ npm install jquery --save
$ npm install webpack --save-dev
```

> Now let's create our app's entry point, in plain ES5 for now:
>
> src/index.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');

$('body').html('Hello');
```

> And let's create our Webpack configuration, in a webpack.config.js file. 
>   Webpack configuration is just Javascript, and needs to export an
>   object:
>
> webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry:  './src',
    output: {
        path:     'builds',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
};
```

How does webpack know what is jquery in `require('jquery')`? I don't see any configuration options specified related to jquery.

Comment: Well, it just downloads jquery and puts it into `node_modules` folder and adds it as a dependency to `package.json`. How's that related to webpack?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, it's going to work just like CommonJS `require`s (e.g., Node `require`s). (Webpack's `require`s support more flexibility than traditional `require`s, but the default behavior is the same.)

[This Modules section in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) explains how Node figures out what to return from a call to `require()`. If you require 'jquery', it first looks for a native module of that name, doesn't find one, and then looks in `node_modules` (because there's no `/` or `./` at the beginning of your path). Since 'jquery' is a folder, it looks at the `package.json` file to see what it declares the `main` file of the package to be, and that's what it executes.

It's worth reading the whole thing; the caching part, for example, is important to know.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so what you saying is that webpack simply delegates `require` call to `Node` and uses whatever it returned?

Comment: @Maximus It does other stuff to support more flexible require resolution, plugins, etc. ... but yes, I think if you write node-style `require`s, it ultimately delegates to Node. Certainly the behavior is the same.

Comment: webpack doesn't delegate to node.js require. It's a complete independent implementation of the node.js resolving algorithm (plus more stuff). This is the library webpack uses for resolving: https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve